# Brackets ругается на работающий скрипт

Tags: javascript, brackets

Здравствуйте. Объясните пожалуйста, почему редактор ругается на скрипт, который, в принципе, работает? Это проблема редактора или ошибка в коде? Как правильно делать, чтобы избежать такой ситуации? (листинг+скриншот ниже)

[image: screenshot]

```
    function insertRow(id) {
        var tbody = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
        var row; 
        row = document.createElement("tr");
        var cellCounter = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
        var td1 = document.createElement("td");
        td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellCounter));
        var td2 = document.createElement("td");
        var checkbox = document.createElement("input")
        checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        td2.appendChild(checkbox);
        var td3 = document.createElement("td");
        td3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("add_id").value));
        var td4 = document.createElement("td");
        td4.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("quant_id").value));
        var td5 = document.createElement("td");
        td5.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("price_id").value));
        var td6 = document.createElement("td");
        td6.appendChild(document.createTextNode("action1"));
        var td7 = document.createElement("td");
        td7.appendChild(document.createTextNode("action2"));
        row.appendChild(td1);
        row.appendChild(td2);
        row.appendChild(td3);
        row.appendChild(td4);
        row.appendChild(td5);
        row.appendChild(td6);
        row.appendChild(td7);
        tbody.appendChild(row);
    }
```

Файл .eslintrc:

```
{
"root": true,

"extends": "@ljharb",

"rules": {
    "complexity": [2, 15],
    "eqeqeq": [2, "allow-null"],
    "func-name-matching": [1],
    "max-depth": [1, 4],
    "max-statements": [2, 26],
    "no-extra-parens": [1],
    "no-magic-numbers": [0],
    "no-restricted-syntax": [2, "BreakStatement", "ContinueStatement", "DebuggerStatement", "LabeledStatement", "WithStatement"],
    "sort-keys": [0],
}
```

}

Comment: Отредактируйте сообщение и скопируйте код.

Comment: @Александр готово

Comment: на скрине не видно первые 2 ошибки

Comment: @Александр поправил скрин

Comment: Прикрепите,что у Вас в файле .eslintrc

Comment: @Александр добавил в пост

Comment: Добавьте в файл eslintrc "globals": {"window": true,"document": true },

Comment: @Александр к сожалению не помогло. может я что-то не так делаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы решить эту проблему необходимо открыть Менеджер расширений в редакторе, через поиск найти расширение "**brackets-eslint**" и установить его.