# Brackets alert is not defined

Tags: javascript, brackets, adobe-brackets

Есть проблема с простым кодом js, долго ищу ответ и не могу понять что делать. Выдает ошибку с alert, console.log,document.write
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прочитал что нужно установить параметр "devel": true, через конфигуратор jsLink включил параметр, одна ошибка убирается но остается вторая. Что делать?Заранее спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

js:

```
/*jslint devel: true*/
alert("text");
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" >
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body> 
<h2>text</h2>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Код нужно вставлять тексто, а не изображением.

Comment: @Эникейщик, а смысл?

Comment: @Qwertiy Вам на этих скриншотах текст ошибки виден? Мне - нет.

Comment: @Эникейщик 1. На скриншот можно нажать, тогда видно всё. 2. Текст ошибки написан в заголовке вопроса. 3. Код верный - вопрос по настройке редактора.

Comment: @Qwertiy  Да много чего можно. Но если спрашивающий не утруждает себя нормальным оформлением вопроса, то зачем отвечающим  утруждать себя. Особенно когда из вопроса даже непонятно о чем вопрос, как вы верно заметили.

Comment: @Эникейщик, я не понимаю, зачем в вопросе по настройке редактора тебе нужна строчка кода с alert'ом. Можешь объяснить?

Comment: первый раз пишу, не знал как правильно оформлять

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/756660/178988 & https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/842224/178988 - установка brackets-eslint не помогает?

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо, вроде бы работает